# how to create firestore composite index for conditional query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using react and fetching docs from my firestore collection. and when i fetch the docs i assigned a conditional query and the query direction changes depending on the value provided.

```
const getData = async () => {
    const constraints = [];

    if (price)
      constraints.push(orderBy("price", price == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

    if (date)
      constraints.push(orderBy("postedDate", date == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

    if (type)
      constraints.push(orderBy("type", type == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

     // there are more conditional queries here. 8 more to be exact

    const livings = collection(db, "livingPosts");
    let q = query(livings, ...constraints);

    const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const dataQ = qSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    // console.log(dataQ);
    setDatas(dataQ);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

as you can see in the above code i've implemented conditional query. and there are more queries that i have not included. so my question is that how can i create indexes for all of these queries?

i created indexes with the link firebase provided me to create it. but it made me create 4 composite indexes just for 2 queries. (for price and date), the order is

```
price - asc , date - asc
price - desc , date - asc
price - asc , date - desc
price - desc , date - asc
```

these were the indexes. so do i have to create every possible indexes like these? if so there are number of combinations i have to do and the max number of indexes are 200. please show me the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So do i have to create every possible indexes like these

Yes you need to create all the indexes corresponding to the queries your app may potentially execute.

For that you can use the URL present in the error messages (which means that you need to execute all the possible queries, i.e. play all the scenarii) or you can use the Firebase (or [Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/indexes/composite?project=xxx&pli=1&authuser=2)) consoles to build them manually.

For the default limit of maximum 200 composite indexes you can actually contact the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to ask for an increase of  this maximum number.

Comment: i don't understand one thing,  let's say the user filtered the price and the date. as i showed above i created the indexes for that, but when the user add filters for the type on top of the others. so what does the index structure look like? i mean if i have created an index containing all fields and scenario, and the user only used some does it work?

Comment: let me give u an example.  lets say i created an index `price - asc , date - asc , type - asc, subs - asc` and run every scenario containing these 4 fields. and if the user only filters the `price` and `date`, do i have to create `price - asc , date -asc`? or does it work if the scenario is included in all fields index?

Comment: You need to create the indexes for ALL cases.

Comment: can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435467/how-to-query-array-of-objects-in-firestore

Comment: thanks it helped, but i'm still confused on the indexing. it is not complaining when i use multiple fields when i use `where()` it only complains with `orderBy()`

Comment: Yes, this is normal. More explanations in this [Firebase video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) on Firestore indexing